# How to use Collections.sort () in java?

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections

I have a simple class - Person.

```
public class Person {
    private int age;

    public Person(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int GetAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

I cread the list of person range from 10 to 20 years old.
Now, I would like to sort the list using Collections.sort() method, but I don't understand how this works.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
        List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
        list.add(new Person (11));
        list.add(new Person (13));
        list.add(new Person (32));
        list.add(new Person (10));

        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator <Person>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Person a1, Person a2) {
                return a1.GetAge() > a2.GetAge();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: This just doesn't work at all.

Comment: did it even compile? compare should return int not boolean as in your case.

Comment: no it doesn't compile. `a1.GetAge() > a2.GetAge()` returns a `boolean`. @MikhailDedyukhin See duffymo's answer.

Comment: using Java 8 you can use something like this :
`Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparingInt(value -> value.GetAge()));`

Comment: I tried use your example but this not works. I have Java 8,

Comment: @MikhailDedyukhin no way it doesn't work, just make sure you config your project to use java 8

Comment: @Snoob Or you can: `Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(Person::GetAge));`

Answer (score 5):

Your Comparator is wrong.  Try this:

```
 public int compare(Person a1, Person a2) {
     return a1.getAge().compareTo(a2.getAge());      
 }
```

or

```
 public int compare(Person a1, Person a2) {
     return (a1.getAge() - a2.getAge());      
 }
```

Think about the contract for Comparator.  It returns an int, not boolean.

Comment: using Integer.compare(..., ...) would be more clear

Comment: That's a matter of opinion.  I'd focus on understanding what the method returns.  If you know that, either one is clear.

Answer (score 3):

Generally in your @Override implementation of the compare() function, you will want something that returns -1, 0, or 1 (generally an int). So, in this case you would want something like this:

```
@Override
    public int compare(Person a1, Person a2) {
        return a1.GetAge().compareTo(a2.GetAge());
    }
```

This will order Person a1 and Person a2 based on age. Depending on the order you want (ascending vs descending) you can do the comparison as a2.GetAge().compareTo(a1.GetAge()); and that will work just fine as well.

You will also need to consider the case that both values are equal (which is when you would return 0).